# How to handle different user time zones in php?

Tags: php

I'm creating a Ad Service thing, the user uploads a image and the Ad goes live for 1 week my problem is that how do i handle different time zones and days?

Because I want to run a Cron job to disable them.

Lets say a user creates a ad today 12/10/2017 from USA

how would i get the users timezone and calculate 7 days from it?

Comment: you have to take input for country/timezone in user profile

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.